# CSS style effect involving z-index and transparency

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a design close to the snippet here. My problem is that I can't find a way to replace the blue background of `.title` by a simple transparency (so that the container's background stays visible). If I simply remove the blue background, the border becomes visible where `.title` is.

Also the "title" is generated by JS so I can't reliably predict the length of div as it may slightly vary depending on the situation.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/94/90/19/9490199f30fc9db039de091205e73be6--backgrounds-wallpapers-phone-backgrounds.jpg');
}

.zone {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.title span {
  display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 20px;
 color: hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
 cursor: default;
 background: hsla(200, 70%, 55%, 1);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
 border-radius: 0rem;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Text Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve what I'm trying to do ? Please let me know if my explanation is too brief or unclear.

Thank you !

Comment: So, you don't want that strike through on the text?

Comment: absolutely ! i want the border to stop where `.title` is while allowing the background of the container to remain visible. I've seen that design on several websites in the past but I don't know what the trick is...

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with pseudo elements. Take a look at this:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/94/90/19/9490199f30fc9db039de091205e73be6--backgrounds-wallpapers-phone-backgrounds.jpg');
}

.zone {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.title span {
  display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 20px;
 color: hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
 cursor: default;
}

.title span::before,
.title span::after{
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
  width: calc(50% - 40px);
  top: 9px;
}

.title span::before{
  left: 0;
}

.title span::after{
  right: 0;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
 width: 200px;
 border-right: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
  border-left: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
 border-radius: 0rem;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Text Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is a good alternative although I would have to find a way to adjust the pseudo-elements's width when the text is longer/shorter

Answer (score 2):

You can get the desired effect by adding more elements

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/94/90/19/9490199f30fc9db039de091205e73be6--backgrounds-wallpapers-phone-backgrounds.jpg');
}

.zone {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.title__text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 20px;
 color: hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
 cursor: default;
/*  background: hsla(200, 70%, 55%, 1); */
}

.title__border {
  flex: 1;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 0.1rem solid hsla(200, 70%, 20%, 1);
  border-top: 0.1rem solid transparent;
 border-radius: 0rem;
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="title">
      <span class='title__border'></span>
      <span class='title__text'>Text Title</span>
      <span class='title__border'></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And don't use selectors like `.title span`. They do not target specific element and styles used by them cannot be reused somewhere else, which means excessive code duplication. Element selectors (like `.title span`) are also likely to cause problems (you are selecting all spans in `.title` element) whenever you change your code (adding another span with different styles is hard), which means even more duplicated code! Duplicated code = more complex code = code that is harder to maintain!

You should [get BEM](http://getbem.com/) or [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/book/type-module) or any other methodology (you may even create your own).

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try this out alongside the fieldset solution proposed above. What did you mean about `.title span` exactly ? On my code it has an id can target it with JS

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a fieldset with a legend instead of a div:

https://jsfiddle.net/v9p60p6g/1/

```
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 350px;
      height: 250px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/94/90/19/9490199f30fc9db039de091205e73be6--backgrounds-wallpapers-phone-backgrounds.jpg');
    }

    fieldset {
      border: solid black 2px;
    }

    legend {

    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Testtitel</legend>
      Content
    </fieldset>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with fieldset at all but I am definitely going to try this out, thank you!